# SSH Challenge response in Thunar or Nautilus?

Tags: ssh, nautilus, pam, thunar, two-factor-authentication

So I have a project where I need to access a server with SSH that has both priv/pub key and 2FA challenge response verification enabled.

The following works:

- Command Line SSH access
- Using WinSCP in Windows

Both of these prompt for the challenge response code for 2FA.

Is there a way to get Thunar or Nautilus to prompt for and accept challenge responses for SSH? The currently working methods require me to jump around from OS to OS or to SCP files from the command line, I'd like to be able to browse folders and open files for editing. This currently works with SSH keys only but not if 2FA or any type of challenge response is enabled.

Comment: What if you set up `ControlMaster` for the relevant hosts, connect via CLI, and then connect via Thunar using that CLI as the master connection?

Comment: Thank you, will look into it.

Comment: I just checked with the IT security guys and it's a no go. Back to square one, their vendor supplied script on Linux has to see the connection and it doesn't. The solution works in the end just not with our specs.

Comment: If you're using some custom SSH client instead of whatever's available on Ubuntu, then I don't think any of us can help you anyway.

Comment: `ControlMaster` seems to be a client side configuration and does not need any changes in the `ssh` server and the help of the IT security guys. Unless you provide us with more details about your setup and the "vendor supplied" scripts you have to run on your computer, we can't help. It is also not clear which version of Ubuntu you are using. Please add that to your question.